# Записать в массив

Tags: python-3.9

На входе строка чисел, к примеру "3, 2, -6". Как эти числа сразу записать в массив?

Comment: `map(int, input().split())`

Answer (score 1):

метод `split()`, очевидно

```py
s = "3,2,-6"
array = s.split(",")
print(array)
['3', '2', '-6']
```

переменная `array` - это список, членами, которого являются строки, а если необходимо получить список с числовыми значениями, то можно сделать так:

```py
array_int = [int(item) for item in array]
print(array_int)
[3, 2, -6]
```

Comment: Я неправильно сформулировал, есть ли возможность сразу преобразовать в массив чисел ?

Comment: что значит "сразу"? Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос воспроизводимым примером, чтобы было понятно, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Спасибо, вы дополнили как раз то что я просил